# MySQL query exponentially slower with parameter in subquery vs hard-coded value

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query that is querying naughty ip addresses from the last 24 hours and ban count >= 2. I don't want them if they are in an extra naughty ban list from the last 7 days and ban count >= 5. The query takes 3 minutes to run. If I replace `@__cutOff_1` with the actual hard coded date inline in the query instead of a variable, the query takes 2 seconds to run.

Is this a bug in MySQL? The query explainer looks like this:

[image]

I am using the latest MySQL x64 8.0 on Windows 10 x64 as of 2019-07-30. Submissions table has 8 million rows, ip addresses table 360K. All where clauses are indexed.

```
SET @__cutOff_0 = '2019-07-29';
SET @__minBanCount_1 = 2;
SET @__cutOff_1 = '2019-07-23';

SELECT `i`.`IPAddress`, `i`.`BanCount`, MAX(`s`.`Timestamp`) AS `c`
FROM `Submissions` AS `s`
CROSS JOIN `IPAddresses` AS `i`
WHERE (((`s`.`Timestamp` >= @__cutOff_0) AND (`i`.`BanCount` >= @__minBanCount_1)) AND (`s`.`IPAddressId` = `i`.`IPAddress`)) AND `i`.`IPAddress` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `i2`.`IPAddress`
    FROM `Submissions` AS `s2`
    INNER JOIN `IPAddresses` AS `i2` ON `s2`.`IPAddressId` = `i2`.`IPAddress`
    WHERE (`s2`.`Timestamp` >= @__cutOff_1) AND (`i2`.`BanCount` >= 5)
)
GROUP BY `i`.`IPAddress`, `i`.`BanCount`
ORDER BY `c` DESC
```

Comment: Have tried the same query in MS SQL Server and even sqlite, it runs in just a few seconds.

Comment: I think you have answered yourself, then until it is fixed, consider using prepared statements to workaround the issue, rather than MySQL variables.

Comment: This was done using a prepared statement using a C# MySqlCommand and calling Prepare function.

Comment: " All where clauses are indexed."  -- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please post results of A) SHOW INDEX FROM submissions; and SHOW INDEX FROM ipaddresses; for analysis.  Using a version of MySQL with less than 90 days on the street as GA could mean you have to report bugs no one has found in their effort to be on the leading edge of using the newer version.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Posted a bug / feature request with Oracle, they say it is a known issue. So there are two work-arounds:

1] Only use hard-coded values in sub-queries, no parameters. Not really an option for me, but may be for some people.

2] Create a temporary data set and filter the outer query with it in code behind. This is the route I went with. I create a set of strings for the inner query using a separate query, then I filter the outer query with this set in code behind to produce the final set.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, change

```
    CROSS JOIN  `IPAddresses` AS `i`
    WHERE  (`s`.`IPAddressId` = `i`.`IPAddress`)
```

To

```
    JOIN  `IPAddresses` AS `i`  ON  (`s`.`IPAddressId` = `i`.`IPAddress`)
```

Change

```
      AND  `i`.`IPAddress` NOT IN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT `i2`.`IPAddress`
                   ... )
```

to

```
     AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM  AS `IPAddresses` AS `i2` ...
                          WHERE ... AND `i2`.`IPAddress` = `i`.`IPAddress` )
```

And have composite index:

```
Submissions:  INDEX(IPAddressId, Timestamp)  -- in this order
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

If none of my suggestions help, then jynus's workaround (prepared statements) may be best.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing. I had already tried all of this, no change. Only making the date a hard-coded value instead of a parameter fixes things.